# Monitor calls to SQL DB made by a .NET assembly on client

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, logging

We have a .NET application which we no longer have the source code for, which connects to an Oracle DB. I want to work out which stored procedures are called in the Oracle DB from my .NET assembly, however to add a complication, we can't easily access the DB with any sort of admin tools.

We have basic user read-only rights on the DB, we can do anything we like locally. Are there any tools we can use on the client side to work out what the DLL is actually doing when it interacts? My thoughts were something along the lines of log all DB calls made on the client machine via the ODBC driver (as far as I'm aware the calls aren't encrypted, although I'm not sure if this is done by default in the implementation).

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Rather than sniffing the wire, I suggest decompiling the assemblies of your app. ILSpy, dotPeek or reflector will do this for you.

Comment: you can use Wireshark to sniff the wire... but @spender sounds better.

Comment: @spender that sounds great! I'm a little rusty with my .net, I didn't realise decompilation tools existed. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @David : yes, unless deliberately obfuscated, .net assemblies lend themselves very nicely to decompilation.

Comment: Unfortunately, your application is using ODBC directly. If the application used ODP.net, you could set TraceLevel to 1 to log all sql statement from your application. See http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConfig.htm to get more information for ODP.net configuration. I believe ODBC may have the similar to trace sql.